# Why does whey protein powder make porridge much less viscous?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

When I mix whey protein powder into warm porridge (that I cooked in the microwave), the thick porridge becomes much less thick.

I searched this, and I found several forum threads discussing this too so it seems to be a common phenomenon. Happens when cooking porridge on the hob too, not just from mixing protein in after cooking.

I make the porridge through simply heating porridge oats + cow's milk. It doesn't matter if the oats are steel-cut or rolled, part of a fast-cook microwave pack, or completely natural.

How come the porridge becomes more liquidy when whey is stirred into it?

Comment: Seasoned Advice SE often plays with disparate metallurgy and rheology stuff.

Comment: I suspect that the thickness of the porridge is in fact, due to it being a non-Newtonian, shear thickening fluid. When the protein powder is mixed, perhaps the mixture becomes less non-Newtonian. That's just my guess though.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti according to [this podcast](https://www.eatthispodcast.com/spurtle/) I just found, porridge is shear-thinning

Comment: I found that whey proteins are used as thickeners, at least in yogurt.

Comment: @Alchimista that's why this behaviour in porridge is very surprising

Comment: @theonlygusti you have a complicated matrix, so one has to identify and study really in details. What is thickening a fluid yogurt can reduce the viscosity of a thick porridge. In the latter case it suffices, but I am inventing, that the proteins in the powder are smaller than those of milk. Voilà, now the ibterchain interactions are between long and shorter chains, disrupting gels or anyway acting as "lubricants". It is just a possibile mechanism. Or there can be more cysteine, etc.

Comment: Does it contain lecithin as an emulsifier? https://www.renegadedad.net/why-lecithin-is-used-in-whey-protein-powder Also, if hydrolyzed, that also could include chemicals breaking down the starch.